# Is it possible to use the same Django models/views/etc with two different databases?

Tags: django, django-database

I have a Django application and I want to host it using 2 databases - one for test data and the other with real data, with the database path defined by the url accessing the site - ie test.mysite.com versus mysite.com. I looked through the Django docs at using multiple databases and routers, but those examples and others use the databases to split up the apps. For example, all data from the Customer model goes in the customer db, and all data from the User model goes in the user db as defined in settings.py. Is there a way to use one django app and configure two databases, with the db selection based on the url?

Perhaps the best solution is to set up 2 virtual environments, one for mysite.com, and the other for test.mysite.com, and let apache's virtual hosts be the "router". As the app(s) evolve, I can clone the sites from the master git repo.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Mark

Comment: You can use PostgreSQL schemas; but since what you actually want to have is a "staging" or "test" environment I would deploy two copies of the same Django site with a different `settings.py`. This way you can also test code changes before deploying them to the live (`mysite.com`) site.

Comment: You should definitely use two or more virtual environments with their own databases. For this, as Selcuk mentioned, you can use different settings files. The best way is to set the settings module with a virtual variable like ```DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "application.settings.dev"```.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am now using two completely different installations of the same virtualenv and django apps. Seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

You can change them like this in every view `queryset.using(random.choice(settings.READ_ONLY_DATABASES))`